# Unable to import Java classes from Jython module

Tags: java, python, import, jython

**Note:** I found the solution and answered myself. Though, I have no idea why that setting was wrong and caused the problem. I'm still interested in having a good explanation about how Jython import system works; if anyone cares to gain the bounty please answer that.

---

I'm working on an existing Java EE project where I need to do computations in Python. I'm at the first stages of integration tests but I'm already facing an issue. I read [Chapter 10 of Jython book](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/JythonAndJavaIntegration.html) but still can't find a solution. I also read [Chapter 8](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/ModulesPackages.html) (Modules and Packages for Code Reuse) but to me it'is unclear.

An explanation of how Jython import system works and how to configure it would be very appreciated.

**The problem:**

```
$ jython -v
import: 'exceptions' as org.python.core.exceptions in builtin modules
Jython 2.5.3 (2.5:c56500f08d34+, Aug 13 2012, 14:54:35) 
[Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (Oracle Corporation)] on java1.7.0_10
import: import site # precompiled from /home/me/jython/2.5.3/Lib/site$py.class
import: 'sys' as sys in builtin modules
import: import os # precompiled from /home/me/jython/2.5.3/Lib/os$py.class
import: 'errno' as org.python.modules.errno in builtin modules
import: 'posix' as org.python.modules.posix.PosixModule in builtin modules
import: import posixpath # precompiled from /home/me/jython/2.5.3/Lib/posixpath$py.class
import: import stat # precompiled from /home/me/jython/2.5.3/Lib/stat$py.class
import: 'java' as java package
import: 'File' as java class
import: 'IOException' as java class
import: 'org' as java package
import: 'Py' as java class
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import pendulum.generator.BuildingType
import: import pendulum # precompiled from /path/to/project/build/classes/pendulum/__init__$py.class
import: import pendulum.generator # precompiled from /path/to/project/build/classes/pendulum/generator/__init__$py.class
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named BuildingType
```

My question is: what am I doing wrong and how do I fix things to import BuildingType interface successfully? Maybe the problem stands in CLASSPATH, but I have no idea which value could be appropriate.

---

**Code organization:**

```
$ tree build/classes/pendulum/generator/ src/pendulum/generator/
build/classes/pendulum/generator/
├── BuildingType.class
├── __init__.py
└── __init__$py.class

src/pendulum/generator/
├── BuildingType.java
└── __init__.py
```

**Import path defined by a [private Jython registry file](http://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/InstallingJython#Where.27s_the_registry_file):**

```
$ cat ~/.jython 
python.path=\
/path/to/project/build/classes:\
/path/to/project/src:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib/site-packages
```

I'm sure Jython picks up the paths because I checked that with `sys.path` at Jython prompt.

**BuildingType.java**

```
package pendulum.generator;

public interface BuildingType {
    public String getBuildingName();
    public String getBuildingAddress();
    public String getBuildingId();
}
```

Comment: try "from pendulum.generator import BuildingType"

Comment: ImportError: cannot import name BuildingType

Comment: Is jython.jar in jre/lib/ext?

Comment: No, it's in ./.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/Myproject/WEB-INF/lib/jython.jar. I'll copy it in jre/lib/ext and test.

Comment: [1] Maybe it needs to be on the Java CLASSPATH as well as the Python sys.path (?) [2] Try running jython with the '-v' option to debug the import.

Comment: @EricGalluzzo I copied the jar in the right ~jre/lib/ext` dir but nothing changed.

Comment: @StevenD.Majewski unfortunately configuring the CLASSPATH has no effect. I edited the question (now very different from its initial shape) adding debug info.

Comment: OK: I looked at the sources from Chapter 10. Do you have the same 'package' line in your java source ? That could be the problem. ( NEVERMIND -- I see the package line above. SAVE EDITS won't let me discard comments. )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of time wasted in try/catch approach I was able to find the answer myself.

.jython *have* to look like this:

```
python.path=\
/path/to/project/build:\
/path/to/project/src:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib/site-packages
```

Not this:

```
python.path=\
/path/to/project/build/classes:\
/path/to/project/src:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib:\
/home/me/jdevel/extras/2.5.3/Lib/site-packages
```

In particular, **adding `/path/to/project/build/classes` to the import path is wrong** (even if it reflects the filesystem hierarchy), while `/path/to/project/build` is right and solved the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set CLASSPATH as well as python.path.

With the same directory layout, this works for me:

```
jython10$ CLASSPATH=build/classes/  jython -v Building.py
import: 'exceptions' as org.python.core.exceptions in builtin modules
import: import site # precompiled from /usr/local/Java/jython2.5.3/Lib/site$py.class
import: 'sys' as sys in builtin modules
import: import os # precompiled from /usr/local/Java/jython2.5.3/Lib/os$py.class
import: 'errno' as org.python.modules.errno in builtin modules
import: 'posix' as org.python.modules.posix.PosixModule in builtin modules
import: import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/local/Java/jython2.5.3/Lib/posixpath$py.class
import: import stat # precompiled from /usr/local/Java/jython2.5.3/Lib/stat$py.class
import: java package as '/Users/sdm7g/jaxp/jython10/build/classes/pendulum'
import: 'pendulum' as java package
import: 'pendulum' as java package
import: java package as '/Users/sdm7g/jaxp/jython10/build/classes/pendulum/generator'
import: 'pendulum.generator' as java package
import: 'BuildingType' as java class
```

Reference: [Working with CLASSPATH](http://www.jython.org/jythonbook/en/1.0/appendixB.html#working-with-classpath) (Jython Book).

Comment: Big thanks. Without setting classpath I was unable to use my classes from command line (`java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`). From within Eclipse all worked fine, though.